# Facebook Code Generator disappeared from Facebook app / More / Setting & Privacy

Tags: facebook

Today is 2022-04-22 and when I login to Facebook on another laptop,

Facebook tell me to open More/Setting and Privacy, then tap Code Generator
in iPhone/Facebook/More/setting & privacy there is no Code Generator there.

Where is Code Generator, is it removed?

[image: Facebook tell me to open More/Setting and Privacy, then tap Code Generator]

[image: in iphone/facebook/More/setting & privacy there is no]